# Check if the required module is a built-in module

Tags: node.js

I need to check if the module that is going to be loaded is a built-in or an external module. For example, suppose that you have a module named `fs` inside the node_modules directory. If you do `require("fs")` the built-in module will be loaded instead of the module inside node_modules, so I'm sure that this question has a solution.

Example:

```
var loadModule = function (moduleName){
  if (isCoreModule (moduleName)){
    ...
  }else{
    ...
  }
};

loadModule ("fs");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`process.binding('natives');` returns an object that provides access to all built-in modules, so getting the keys of this object will get you the module names. So you could simply do something like:

```
var nativeModules = Object.keys(process.binding('natives'));

function loadModule(name) {
  if (~nativeModules.indexOf(name)) {
    // `name` is a native module name
  } else {
    // ...
  }
};

loadModule('fs');
```

Comment: Why not simply `if (process.binding('natives')[moduleName]) //built-in module`, performance maybe? each property has a string value, a super-big string :S. Anyway, thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `require.resolve.paths(str)`:

1- if `str` is core module the call will return `null`.

2- if `str` is not core module you will get an array of strings.

Comment: The wierd thing is `require.resolve.paths('path:fs')` returns an array of strings, so if ur checking `node:module` is built-in u have to remove the `node:` part.

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be: `require.resolve(moduleName).indexOf('/') <= 0`. If that is true, it's a core module. Might not be portable to windows as implemented, but you should be able to use this idea to get going in the right direction.

Aside: beware `require.resolve` does synchronous filesystem IO. Be careful about using it within a network server.

Aside: Careful with the term "native" which generally means a native-code compiled add-on, or a C/C++ implementation. Both "core" and community modules can be either pure JS or native.
I think "core" is the most accurate term for built-in modules.

Aside: best not to shadow global variable names, so `moduleName` instead of just `module` which can be confusing with the global of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Module.isBuiltin Added in: [v18.6.0, v16.17.0](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#moduleisbuiltinmodulename)

```
import { isBuiltin } from 'node:module';
isBuiltin('node:fs'); // true
isBuiltin('fs'); // true
isBuiltin('fs/promises'); // true
isBuiltin('wss'); // false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This should be now the accepted answer. The other suggestion of using `process.binding('natives')[moduleName]` doesn't handle the new syntax of `node:<core-module>`.